# AWS lambda exceeding 900 seconds limit

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a lambda that compares sentences using Jaccard and Cosine Similarity.
However, the functions does the comparison words wise, and has many nested for loops.

I am afraid that the function will exceed the time limit of lambda on AWS.

If my function is too inefficient for AWS lambda, what are some alternatives that I can try?

Comment: `what are some alternatives that I can try?` what do you mean by this, do it in some other language, or some other way to achieve it in AWS or something else? it is little bit unclear

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. But, essentially I still want to stay serverless by using lambda and python. Just that my code may run for more than 900 seconds, and was wondering what else I can do aside from cleaning up my python code.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of 900 seconds is hard, you cant do anything with it. Keep in mind that increasing memory of lambda also increases cpu, so your code executes faster. If it's not enough you might split your code into multiple functions and aggregate them with Step Functions or by storing output in storage like Dynamodb. I'm guessing your priority is to stay serverless. If that's the case you can also contenerize your app